# Inverse functions when will $\sin(\arcsin x)$ be defined

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

So first i know $\sin(x)$ has a domain of $\mathbb{R}$ and a codmain of $[-1,1]$ while the $\arcsin(x)$ is the opposite, domain of $[-1,1]$ with a codmain of $\mathbb{R}$. So $\sin(\arcsin(x)) = x$. But will $
\sin(\arcsin(10)) = 10$? I would like to think no because $10$ is not in the domain of $\arcsin(x)$. But using the identity it is equal to $10$. Can someone help me understand which logic is correct?

Comment: Your logic is correct. $\sin x$ is not a $1-1$ fuction.  We need to restrict the domain for the inverse.   $\arcsin x$ is the inverse function of $\sin x$ only when $x$ is in $[-\frac {\pi}{2}, \frac \pi{2}]$.

Answer (score 1):

The equality is only true on the proper domain of $\sin$ and $\arcsin.$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\arcsin 10$ is not defined, neither is $\sin (\arcsin 10)$.